On a differential inequality with an additional constraint
I am stuck on this problem from a research question, which seems to require solving a differential equation, but I am not sure how to deal with integrals like $\int_0^t$ or $\int_t^1$. I will be grateful for any direction or help. Many thanks!
For some function $p: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$, find $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_+$ such that:

(1) $\displaystyle \int_t^1 f(s) ds \ge \int_t^1 \alpha(s) ds$ where $\displaystyle \alpha(t) = 1 - \int_0^t p(s) f(s) ds$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.
(2) $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(s) ds \le 1$

I have a guess that $f(t)$ should somehow relate to $\displaystyle s(t) := \frac{\int_0^t p(s) ds}{p(t)}$, for example $f(t) = s(t) \cdot \exp(-s(t))$ etc.
Note 1: One of my attempts is to set $f(s) = \alpha(s)$ or $f(s) = \exp(\alpha(s) - 1)$ and solve the differential equations, but the corresponding solutions do not satisfy Condition (2).

The function $f$ with
$$f(t)=f_0(t):=\exp\Big(-\int_0^t p\Big)$$
for $t\in[0,1]$ will do.
Indeed, then $f'=-pf$, $\int_0^t pf=-\int_0^t f'=1-f(t)$, $\alpha=f$, so that your condition (1) holds, with the equality.
Also, $p\ge0$ implies $f\le1$, so that your condition (2) holds as well. $\quad\Box$

The OP asked in a comment if we can have the equality in (2) (while keeping (1)). The answer to this is also yes. Indeed, if we now let $f=f_0+c$, where $c:=1-\int_0^1 f_0$, then $c\ge0$ and (2) will hold with the equality: $\int_0^1 f=1$. We will also have $\int_t^1 pf\ge\int_t^1 pf_0$ and hence $\alpha(t)=1-\int_0^t pf\le1-\int_0^t pf_0=f_0(t)\le f(t)$, so that (1) will still hold.

Thanks for the answer! This is what I got as well when setting $f = \alpha$, but how does it satisfy (2) (with the integration)?

@lntk : One cannot just set $f=\alpha$, because $\alpha$ depends on $f$. That would be trying to define $f$ in terms of an undefined $f$ itself. However, with $f$ as in my answer and $p\ge0$, we have $f\le1$, so that your condition (2) holds, as explained in the answer.

Thanks! By setting $f = \alpha$ I meant (taking the derivative of both sides and) solving the resulting differential equation (which leads to a solution similar to what you've given, i.e., $f(t) = \exp(-\int_0^t p(s) ds)$ if I understand it correctly). However, I just realized that $f(t) \le 1 \forall t \in [0, 1]$ implies $\int_0^1 f(s) ds \le 1$ as the area is inside the unit square. Thanks for the answer!

If Condition (2) is changed into $\int_0^1 f = 1$, is there a way to achieve it? Thanks

@lntk : Concerning the additional question in your latter comment, I don't know an answer to it at this point. Additional questions should be posted separately. In particular, that way you can give them a broader exposure.
